# Enable tabs in pyqt after loading a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm designing a pyqt app where the main layout has some tabs. The first tab is where a user loads a default directory (tab1). All the other tabs cant be enabled without loading a directory. I have been trying to enable the tabs after loading a directory but no success till now. If anyone could help me it will mean a lot.

My folder structure is like this:

```
ABC (Main folder)
    --files (sub folder)
        --tab1.py
        --tab2.py
    --home.py
```

In the home.py im setting the tab2 to be disabled from default and when a user loads a directory in tab1 i want it to be enabled.

**Here are my codes for the three pages:**

home.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from files.tab1 import Test
from files.tab2 import Tests

# Creating the main window
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
  
        self.show()
  
# Creating tab widgets
class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(Test(), "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(Tests(), "Tab2")
        # Add tabs to widget
        self.tabs.setTabEnabled(1,False)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

tab1.py

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, 
                            QFileDialog, 
                            QHBoxLayout, 
                            QVBoxLayout, 
                            QPushButton, 
                            QLabel, 
                            QApplication)

#CREATING SUBCLASS OF WIDGET

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Home')

#layout
        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        
        verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.opendir = QPushButton("Select Working Directory")
        self.dirLabel = QLabel("Selected Directory: None")
        
        
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.opendir)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dirLabel)
        
        horizontalLayout.addLayout(verticalLayout,1)
         
        self.setLayout(horizontalLayout)

#SIGNALS
        
        self.opendir.clicked.connect(self.loadworkdir)
    
    workdir = os.path.expanduser("~")

    def loadworkdir(self):
        global workdir

        self.dialog = QFileDialog()
        workdir = self.dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder",os.path.expanduser("~"))
        if workdir == '':
            self.dirLabel.setText('Selected Directory: None')
        else:
            self.dirLabel.setText('Working Directory : {}'.format(workdir))

        return workdir
    
    def setupdir(self):
        global x
        x = workdir
        return x
```

tab2.py

```
import sys
import os
import glob
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, 
                            QFileDialog, 
                            QHBoxLayout, 
                            QVBoxLayout, 
                            QPushButton, 
                            QLabel, 
                            QApplication)
from files.tab1 import *

class Tests(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tests, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Home')
        
        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        
        verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.opendir1 = QPushButton("Select files")
        self.shapeLabel = QLabel()
        
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.opendir1)
        
        horizontalLayout.addLayout(verticalLayout,1)
         
        self.setLayout(horizontalLayout)
        
        self.opendir1.clicked.connect(self.loadfiles)

    def loadfiles(self):
        self.dir=Test.setupdir(self)
        os.chdir(self.dir)
        self.dialog = QFileDialog()
        self.fpath = self.dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")
        csvcounter = len(glob.glob1(self.fpath,"*.csv"))
        self.shapeLabel.setText('CSV Files:{}'.format(csvcounter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a signal for the first tab:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Test(QWidget):
    directoryLoaded = pyqtSignal(str)
    # ...
    def loadworkdir(self):
        global workdir

        self.dialog = QFileDialog()
        workdir = self.dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder",os.path.expanduser("~"))
        if workdir == '':
            self.dirLabel.setText('Selected Directory: None')
        else:
            self.dirLabel.setText('Working Directory : {}'.format(workdir))

        self.directoryLoaded.emit(workdir)

        return workdir
```

Then connect it to a function that enables the second tab in the main script:

```
class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        # create a reference to the first tab, because we need to connect to its signal
        firstTab = Test()
        firstTab.directoryLoaded.connect(self.firstTabLoaded)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(firstTab, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(Tests(), "Tab2")
        # Add tabs to widget
        self.tabs.setTabEnabled(1, False)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

        # not required: you already set it by adding "self" to the constructor
        # self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def firstTabLoaded(self, path):
        self.tabs.setTabEnabled(1, bool(path))
```

<sup>Note: avoid using globals, they should not be used unless you **really** know what they are and how they work, and certainly should *not* be used like you're trying to: both `x` and `workdir` are valid in the scope of their script, so trying to access or change them from another script will have absolutely no result.</sup>

Comment: Thankyou sir for the help. It is working. I used global so that i can access that variable in other tabs. Can u show something to pass value between tabs ? i asked that question here but deleted it cause it was unclear as said by others.

Comment: And can u explain the function firstTabLoaded what is the path and bool(path). I didnt get it.

Comment: if i select a directory in tab1 then the tab2 gets enabled but when i again click on select directory button and close it without selecting the directory the tab2 gets disabled again.

Comment: @USer12345 Using `bool` against a string results in having a `True` value if the string has contents or `False` if it's empty; since `setTabEnabled` only accepts bool values, that conversion allows using a proper type so that the tab gets enabled if a path is provided or disabled if it's not; if you don't want to disable the tab is a second file dialog is rejected, then add a check for the enabled tab: `if path and not self.tabs.isTabEnabled(1):` `self.tabs.setTabEnabled(1, True)`; in this way you don't risk that it gets enabled even if the file dialog is rejected the first time.

Comment: About globals, I know why you tried to use it, but that's *not* what globals should be used for, it's not the proper way to access variables between instances, and, as explained, it wouldn't work anyway because you're trying to access a global from another module which exists in a different scope. Unfortunately the topic is too complex to give you an answer in a comment, and it's also completely off topic for this post. I suggest you to do some more research on OOP, and have better understanding of classes, instances and variable scopes.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanations. yes globals are too confusing. I will look into the things u suggested. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: I ran into a problem. If i select a directory in tab 1 and again click on select a directory and close the select window without choosing a directory..Now in the tab2 the directory that i have selected also gets erased i guess. It shows error.

Comment: Please try to be more clear in your comments, don't provide only partial informations that require further comments: 1. What do you mean by "the directory that i have selected also gets erased i guess"? 2. "It shows error": **what** error?!?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
What I meant is:
1. I load a directory in tab1 then tab2 gets enabled and i can click on select files in tab2 and it shows the selected directory from tab1.
2. If i do the above step and then again click on select directory in tab1 and close the window without selecting a new directory then tab2 still remains enabled but when i click on select files there it throws an error like this :  [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''.

Comment: I specifically used the `bool(path)` check exactly to avoid this kind of UI-logic issues. Unfortunately, with that little information I don't really know where does that error come from, but I suspect that could be the result of your wrong usage of globals: run your script in a terminal/prompt and see the full traceback: if it's in the QFileDialog constructor, you get another reason for avoiding globals (which is still the same: don't use them unless you *really* know how they work); if it's the csvcounter line, that's because you didn't manage a rejected dialog (which returns an empty string)

Comment: In either case, sorry but I cannot help you further more on those aspects, as they are off topic to the question, and they really are aspects on which you have to work much more, since they only relate to the studying of underlying logic of how your program should behave (what happens if the tab is enabled and the file dialog is ignored? What if the same path is selected? Etc...) and proper usage of classes, instances and attributes, instead of using globals.